# read-string in clojure gives EOF while reading

Tags: clojure

I have the following string after evaluating the expression `(slurp (:body req))`:

```
(prn (slurp (:body req)))
;; gives "{:foo \"abc\"}"         -------- (1)
```

But when I try to read it into edn:

```
(prn (read-string (slurp (:body req))))
```

And wrap it around try, catch, I get the EOF while reading exception.

But when I copy paste result (1) directly into the repl and do `(read-string "{:foo \"abc\"}")`, it gives the expected map. Why is this?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you aren't trying to read the body more than once? If it's already been read, you can't read it again from the same request. Please provide a reproducer complete enough to let us be confident that this isn't happening.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but pretty important. Are you aware of the dangers of `read-string`? If not, you should really not use it. Use the functions in `clojure.edn` instead.

Comment: Why are you using slurp here? Is it the case that the value of `(:body req)` is a path to a file?